# 3 phase temperature controller

Tags: electrical, temperature

I am trying to control a 3 phase fan based on the temperature of a liquid in a tank. I have been searching for a simple temperature controller like the ink bird one, but for 3 phase but i cant find anything like that similar for 3 phase.

Does anyone know of a simple on/off temperature controller for a 3 phase connection?

Answer (score 2):

On/Off control? Any temperature controller you like, and a three phase relay (or "contactor" is common for 3-phase terminology) that takes the output of the temperature controller you like as input.

3-pole would be an alternate term for 3-phase in searching.

Plus a box to hold it all safely...

***Not What you asked, but:*** *"Fancy" 3-phase control would use a Variable Frequency Drive (VFD) that looked at your temperature input to vary the **speed** of the fan.*